# Can i make these circles for my <li> points in css?

Tags: css

I am trying to make this menu

[image: gun shop]

now so far i can get to [this point](https://jsfiddle.net/mson9zee/) where i have the `>` appearing before each `<li>` with a margin of 10px before the text but the problem is that i can't get the circle

i tried adding [`<divs>`](https://jsfiddle.net/mson9zee/1/) thinking i could just give it a `background-color` and `border-radius` but the problem is that the html comes up as text so i wouldn't be able to apply any css to it.

the easiest solution would be to add a `<div>` in each `<li>` however the list is generated by a php function which returns the HTML as a single string. i could use `str_replace()` to locate every opening `<li>` and add in a `<div>` or do the same thing in javascript but i want to know if i can do this though CSS

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
li::before {
    content: ">";
    background: gold;
    font-family: serif;
    font-style:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    line-height: .8em;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**EDIT:** updated to make it look better.

Comment: thanks. i never thought to think of the `<li>` or even the `::before` like a `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `li:before` with a content of `>` to make these bullet points, like so:

```
li:before {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fcbe35;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    content: '>';
    display: inline-flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 24px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mj638qy/).

Comment: thanks. i never thought to think of the `<li>` or even the `::before` like a `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

How about making those circles in a Photo Editing Software and using them as the `marker` of your list like this :-

```
li{
list-style-image : url("circles.gif");
}
```

Or if you just don't want to use an Image :-

```
li::before{
content : ">";
background : yellow;
border-radius : 50%;
/* and some other styles as per your wish */
}
```

Comment: thanks. i never thought to think of the `<li>` or even the `::before` like a `<div>`. also didn't know about `list-style-image`, i just use `list-style:none` when i want to wipe it out

Answer (score 0):

use an image: `list-style-image: url(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo elements as 'li::before' to adjust the pointers dynamically using only CSS.